# Crear función de evento scroll para vista móvil en Typescript

Tags: typescript, scroll, rxjs

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de código que gestiona cuando se hace scroll con las teclas arriba y abajo del teclado:

```
KeyEvents() {

    if (this.subskey != undefined)
      this.subskey.unsubscribe();

    this.subskey = this.APPService.keyEvent$.subscribe((event) => {

      switch (event.keyCode) {

        case this.keyCodes.KEY_UP:
          this.isText('UP');
          break;
        case this.keyCodes.KEY_DOWN:
          this.isText('DOWN');
          break;
      }
    });
  }
```

Después con la función isText(direccion) y un switch ya puedo hacer las acciones que quiera según me mueva hacia abajo o hacia arriba. Por ejemplo cuando me muevo hacia abajo poner una flecha.
Lo que quiero es hacer lo mismo pero para un evento de swipe, es decir, si hago swipe hacia abajo o hacia arriba hacer distintas acciones. Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con este ejemplo de la web W3Schools, está en javascript, pero creo que también es funcional en Typescript si copias y pegas.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_to_top.asp

Si haces un click en el ejemplo y luego pulsas la tecla abajo, verás que también aparece el botón de "volver arriba", incluso si le das a F12 en el navegador y lo pones en modo móvil, también aparece el botón cuando haces swipe.

Aún así, no veo mucho sentido a lo que intentabas hacer, en el móvil no existen las teclas arriba y abajo, si no me equivoco...

Comment: Lo que busco es hacer un evento o algo para saber cuando el scroll está arriba de todo o abajo de todo. Si está arriba necesito poner unha flecha en una parte del html y si está al final necesito poner una flecha en otra parte del html.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que comentas, estás utilizando RxJS sobre los eventos de teclado (keyEvent$). Puedes utilizar una aproximación similar, pero creándote tu propio observable basado en el evento de "scroll":

```
const scrolling$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'scroll');
```

De esta manera podrás ser notificada de cuando se ha hecho un scroll, analizar la posición:

```
const scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
```

Un ejemplo completo lo puedes encontrar [aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/observable-scroll-soes), con Angular y RxJS de manera integrada. Indica luego si te sirvió.

Comment: Exacto, eso es lo que quiero hacer. Me podrías poner como quedaría el código con este método (es la primera vez que  uso angular y estoy algo perdida). Además Rx me pone que no lo encuentra. Espero que me puedas ayudar. gracias

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Angular y Rx estás utilizando?

Comment: Angular CLI: 6.0.5
rxjs 6.2.0

Comment: Edito la respuesta y te dejo el ejemplo completo. Con el código anterior te diría que no existe Rx por los imports desde Angular, que no se haría así, sino como te muestro en el proyecto de StackBlitz

Comment: No consigo que me funcione. Yo lo que quería es hacer una función en lugar de KeyEvents una que sea SwipeEvents y con la misma estructura. Si el swipe baja hacer una determinada tarea y si sube otra. Espero que puedas ayudarme a realizar esa función. Muchas gracias.